# how i'm going to include connection file in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, oracle11g

i'm using vb.net and oracle.
this is my code connection with db

```
     Dim connectionString As String = "Data Source = abc; User ID = abc; Password = abc;"
     Dim sqlConnection As OracleClient.OracleConnection = New OracleClient.OracleConnection(connectionString)
```

and this is what i save inside the apps.config

```
    <add key="abc_connection" value="server=xyz;User ID=abc;Password=abc;database=abc;Connection Timeout=0"/>
```

what code i should use for replacing my code connection above ? so that i can call the apps.config file instead of using the code connection repeatly.

Comment: Please expand the app.config text including the section in which that key appears

Comment: sorry i dont understand what do u mean

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class with settings and add a property

web config

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="connectionstring" connectionString="server=xyz;UserID=abc;Password=abc;database=abc;Connection Timeout=0" />
```

cs code

```
    public static string connStr
    { get { return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["abc_connection"].ConnectionString; } }
```

if you want to use key in appconfig

```
 public static string abc_connection
    { get {return  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["abc_connection"].ToString(); } }
```

in vb

```
  Public Shared Function connStr() As String
    Return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("abc_connection").ConnectionString ''
End Function

Public Shared Function abc_connection() As String
    Return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("abc_connection") ''
End Function
```

Comment: This assumes that you retrieve the data from the connectionStrings section but this is not true [key=xxxxx] value=[xxxxx] are not valid terms in the connectionStrings section

Comment: I have put and for key and for connectionStrings.

Comment: thank you.but i get a little bit confuse how is it in vb.net ?

Comment: I will port it in a minute :)